# c++ operator<<(char) but out but in hexa/int

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

why do the three operator<< output different way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  operator<<(cout, "Hello").operator<<('w').operator<<(endl); // Hello119

  cout << (void *)'w' << endl; // 0x77

  cout << 'w'; // w

  operator<<(operator<<(cout, "Hello"), 'w').operator<<(endl); // Hellow !!!
}
```

The first operator<< with 2 arguments give the right output for string as expected while the others don't ...

Could someone please explain it to me more?

---

More info:

`cout << "Hello" << 'w' << endl;` would be interpreted as...

`operator<<(operator<<(cout, "Hello"), 'w').operator<<(endl); // Hellow`

Comment: What part of this output is unexpected?  If you look at an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) you can see what the decimal and hex representations of `'w'` are.

Comment: I expected a chain call of the `.operator<<(<char>)` member function would yield the same output as I chain the `<< <char>` as normal.

Comment: I figured it out... this would work: `operator<<(operator<<(cout, "Hello"), 'w').operator<<(endl); // Hellow`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing a forced cast to a `void` pointer and there's a specialization for the `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,void*);`, hence you get the output as hex value not as decimal.

Note: 0x77 == 119

Also note:

You are calling the [`std::ostream::operator<<()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) member operator overload here:

```
   operator<<(cout, "Hello").operator<<('w').operator<<(endl);
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// |                         |
// |                         + Calls the std::ostream::operator<<() member operator
// + Calls the std::ostream& operator(std::ostream, T) global overload
```

There's no overload for `char`, hence an implicit conversion to `int` is taken and the numeric value `119` appears in the output.

As from the above linked reference of the `std::ostream::operator<<()` member function:

[image]
As you mentioned in comments

```
std::cout << 'w' << 'w' << 'w' << std::endl;
```

will be deduced to chained calls of the global [`std::ostream& operator<<(std:: ostream&, T)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) overload:

```
operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(std::cout,'w'),'w'),'w'),std::endl);
```

Comment: Missing answer why `.operator('w')` outputs `int` instead of `char`

Comment: @Slava Because `char` can be casted to `int` implicitly.

Comment: Why it casted then instead of calling overloaded function, that accepts `char`

Comment: ok but I think that deserves to be added to the answer, that there are methods to accept int, short etc but function accepting `char` is not a member.

Comment: @Slava Well, the link to the appropriate reference and explaining there's no overload isn't enough?

Comment: Maybe yes, but it is not obvious though so it would not bad to mention that explicitly

Comment: @Slava But I mentioned it??

Comment: I agree with @Slava, it's not obvious, because `cout << 'w'` works fine. I finally found it at your link, under Notes: "The arguments of type `char` and `const char*` are handled by the non-member overloads of operator<<." The explanation could be more thorough.

Comment: How can I make: operator<<(cout, "Hello").operator<<('w').operator<<(endl); output Hellow instead of Hello119 ?

Comment: @Thi Just call it the usual way as: `cout, "Hello" << 'w' << endl;` The `operator` keyword is implicit for eerm _operators_.

Comment: but is there any way I call the `ostream.operator<<('w')` and get the output 'w'  instead of 119?

Comment: then why `cout << 'w' << 'w' << 'w'` output www. I mean no matter how long you chained the call of operator<< **member function**, it still output char and not int...

Comment: @Thi These calls will deduce to the global operator overload, did you read that link to the reference from my answer?